# Firebase creating groups using Firebase database in Android

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on an application where the user can create groups and add members to it. But how can I show that change to the user being added as well?

What I have thought is to add the member child to the person being added

[image: This is my database]

`QuV7...` child is the current users uid, `f0925e44`  is the group id, `987456321` is a random number to add the list of users in the group.

Now, is there a way to retrieve the user `Gu Curi` uid? So that I can add the group id and its subsets to `Gu Curi` user id?

Comment: It's unclear what this structure represents. Also why you have a user's name as the key and their uid as the value instead of vice versa. You probably don't want to nest your users in such a deep infrastructure either.

Comment: Well thats true. Will certainly improve on that . Well is there a way to get a users uid of another user. and if not How can groups be created using firebase in android. ?

Comment: What is the end goal? Better to talk about the [X than the Y](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Comment: end goal is to create groups and add members to them. was asking about users uid since I had a possible solution to the prolem using that